# Why if $\phi \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ then $\int_{|x|>R} |\phi| \ dx < \epsilon $

Tags: integration, limits, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Why if $\phi \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ then $\displaystyle\int_{\|\mathbf{x}\|>R} |\phi|\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x} < \epsilon $?

I started the proof by:
Suppose that $\exists \epsilon_0 > 0$ and $j_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall j \geq j_0$,

$$\int_{\|\mathbf{x}\|>R_j} |\phi| \mathrm{d}\mathbf{x} \geq \epsilon_0 $$

I don´t know how to continue. I consider using if $\phi(\mathbf{x}) \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ then $\displaystyle\lim_{\|\mathbf{x}\| \to \infty} |\phi(\mathbf{x})| = 0$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I am guessing that “$R$” you wrote is asymptotic? You can use that $\underset{R\to\infty}{\lim\!\!\uparrow}\int_{|x|\le R}|\phi|\,\mathrm dx=\int_{\Bbb R^d}|\phi|\,\mathrm dx<\infty$ (by monotone convergence), so by difference $$\lim_{R\to\infty}\left[\int_{\Bbb R^d}|\phi|\,\mathrm dx-\int_{|x|\le R}|\phi|\,\mathrm dx\right]=0.$$

Comment: Your last statement isn't correct; for example, take $\phi = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \chi_{[n,n+1/n^2]}$. The $L^1$ norm is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n^2} <\infty$, but the limit at $\infty$ does not exist.

Comment: Dominated convergence: for any $x\in R^d$, $\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{1}_{\{|\phi|>R\}}(x)|\phi(x)|=0$. Thus $\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\{|\phi|>R\}}|\phi| =0$. THe rest is putting things in $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ formalism.

Comment: I am sorry but I haven´t studied measure-theory so I can´t use the dominated convergence. Any ideas of what can I use?

Comment: What have you learned so far? As is suggested by nejimban, are you allowed to use Levy's monotone convergence theorem?